# WebSockets Support On IBM WebSphere Application Server 9.0.5.6

Tags: java, websocket, websphere

I am migrating an enterprise-level application based on JBOSS EAP 7.3 using the WebSocket Servlets to IBM WebSphere Application Server 9.0.5.6 (WAS). The problem is that when I try to connecting to WebSocket endpoint it does nothing. In WebSphere, I have configured all virtual hosts and ports accordingly and my WebSocket endpoint class looks like below.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/WebSocketServices")
public class ClientConnectorWebSocketCore {

    private static final OMSLogHandlerI logger = new Log4j2HndlAdaptor("ClientConnectorWebSocketCore");
    private ClientConnectorFacadeWrapperRemote clientConnectorFacadeRemote;
    private EJBServiceLocatorI ejbServiceLocatorI;

    @OnOpen
    public void onConnectionOpen(Session session) {
        session.setMaxIdleTimeout(120000); //todo //milli seconds
        getEjbServiceLocatorI();
        logger.elkLog("29", LogEventsEnum.WSOCKET_SESSION_CONNECT, " Session Create:" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) {
        return handleJSONRequest(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onConnectionClose(Session session) {
        logger.elkLog("42", LogEventsEnum.WSOCKET_SESSION_CLOSE, " Session Close:" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnError
    public void onConnectionError(Session session, Throwable t) {
//        logger.info("LN:47", session.getId(), LogEventsEnum.WEB_SOCKET_ONERROR, "WebSocket OnException" + t.getMessage());
        logger.elkLog("48", LogEventsEnum.WEB_SOCKET_ONERROR, " Session error:" + session.getId() + ", Msg:" + t.getMessage());
    }

    public void msgBroadCast(Session session, String msg) {
        for (Session session1 : session.getOpenSessions()) {
            if (session1.isOpen()) {
                session1.getAsyncRemote().sendText(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    private EJBServiceLocatorI getEjbServiceLocatorI(){
        if (ejbServiceLocatorI == null){
            ejbServiceLocatorI =
                    (EJBServiceLocatorI) SpringBeanFactoryLoader.getInstance().getBeanLoader().getBean(EJBServiceLocatorI.class);
        }
        return ejbServiceLocatorI;
    }

    private ClientConnectorFacadeWrapperRemote getClientConnectFacade() {
        if (clientConnectorFacadeRemote == null) {
            try {
                ejbServiceLocatorI = getEjbServiceLocatorI();
                clientConnectorFacadeRemote =
                       (ClientConnectorFacadeWrapperRemote) ejbServiceLocatorI.contextLookupConnectorFacadeRemote(ClientConnectorFacadeWrapperRemote.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("LN:66", "Error in Creating Client connector   " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return clientConnectorFacadeRemote;
    }

    private String handleJSONRequest(String jsonRequest) {
        ClientConnectorFacadeWrapperRemote clientConnector = getClientConnectFacade();
        String response = null;
        if (clientConnector != null) {
            response = clientConnector.processMessage(jsonRequest);
        }
        return response;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void pongMessage(Session session, PongMessage msg) {
        msg.getApplicationData().toString();
    }


    public void setEjbServiceLocatorI(EJBServiceLocatorI ejbServiceLocatorI) {
        this.ejbServiceLocatorI = ejbServiceLocatorI;
    }
}
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your requests flow through a web server with WebSphere plugin, you need to ensure plugin is at level 9.0.5.6 or higher due to bug (PH27966) which can block websocket traffic.